# Opening Windows 10 mail via C#

Tags: c#, process

I want to open the windows 10 mail app via C#.

I've found that this can be done by using `Process.Start("mailto:ADDRESS");`, but I don't want to use this since it will open it on the 'Send a mail page'. I just want it to open.

I have also tried to use `Process.Start("HxOutlook.exe");`, because according to the task manager that is the `.exe` but that didn't work.

I hope you'll be able to help me with this issue I'm facing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
Process.Start("outlookmail:");
```